# Ficar "entre a cruz e a espada", significa ficar no meio de duas coisas ruins?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica

**A expressão ainda é de uso corrente em pt-BR e significa encontrar-se em um dilema**. No entanto não consigo entender como poderia ser um dilema ficar entre a cruz — que simboliza algo de bom — e a espada — que pode ferir e matar.  Seria mais fácil de entender se fosse entre o fogo e a espada, ou entre a foice e o sabre. *Ficar entre a cruz e a espada*, se fosse uma expressão nova, eu tenderia a achar que significa "ficar indeciso entre algo bom e algo ruim", ou "algo seguro e algo perigoso".

Gostaria também de perguntar sobre a origem da expressão, que não encontrei mas parece ser bem antiga.

Comment: Para mim *cruz* aí é 'sofrimento, martírio' [(Aulete 4)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cruz); por cá diz-se *entre a espada e a parede*.

Comment: @Jacinto   Interessante.  Pensei que tivesse vindo para o Brasil junto com as caravelas.

Comment: Pode ter ido e cair em desuso aqui. Ou ainda se usar algures. E por aqui eu ouvi frequentemente a pessoas mais velhas usar *cruz* no sentido de 'sofrimento': *cada um tem que carregar a sua cruz* e coisas assim.

Comment: Sim, **carregar** a cruz é sofrimento.  Assim como ser crucificado.  Não havia pensado nisso.

Comment: Mas aí, pensando melhor, é uma alusão à cruz enquanto instrumento de tortura e morte.

Comment: Indo um pouco mais além, tanto a _cruz_, quanto a _espada_ eram instrumentos de execução na Roma antiga. Portanto, escolher uma ou outra não mudaria a consequência (a execução). No inglês, a expressão similar deixa este tipo de dilema mais claro: _between a rock and a hard place_.

Comment: A cruz significa algo bom? Ser pregado e pendurado é bom? Nunca experimentei, mas creio que não é bom...

Comment: @Gabriel   Pergunte àqueles que passam nas ruas se a cruz simboliza algo bom ou ruim.  Aposto quanto você quiser que 9 em 10 dirão que significa tudo de bom.

Comment: @Gabriel Depende. Se as pessoas fizerem associarem a cruz a um símbolo de fé elas vao dizer que é bom, se elas associarem a um símbolo de sacrificio, elas vao dizer que é mau. O Centaurus diz portanto que é mais comum ser atribuida a associacao de fé, nao sei se éverdade ou nao... Só fazendo um estudo.

Comment: Há aí uma lógica errada: não é por algo ser um símbolo de fé que é bom; um cilício é um símbolo de fé, e acho que todos concordamos que não é conotado com "bom". Dito isto: sim, percebo que muitos católicos vejam a cruz como um símbolo de bom; mas não estou convencido que a cruz tenha esse significado para a esmagadora maioria das pessoas.

Comment: @ANeves  Nunca fiz um enquete a respeito mas a julgar pela presença de um crucifixo pendurado no pescoço de muita gente nas ruas, eu apostaria qualquer quantia que a esmagadora maioria dos **brasileiros** associa a cruz com o bem e com o que é bom.  Não sou religioso e não tenho a menor ideia do que seja um "cilício", mas vou olhar no dicionário.   Pronto, já vi.  É aquilo que o fanático usava no filme "O Código Da Vinci".

Comment: @Centaurus, "Cruz" me faz lembrar de "crucificação", que naturalmente é algo que considero ruim. Se 9 em cada 10 associariam a cruz a algo positivo, talvez eu seja o 1 que associa a algo negativo. Agora, já que você se permitiu conjecturar sobre a enquete, farei o mesmo: não acho que passa de 5/10 (obviamente depende muito da região onde a pesquisa é feita). Mas isso já foge da discussão original, então deixemos essa conjectura pra lá.

Comment: @Gabriel   Exato. Se fizeres a enquete entre aqueles que estão saindo da igreja no final da missa de domingo, o resultado é um.  Se a enquete for feita entre jovens de 20 a 30 anos ao sairem do motel, o resultado é outro.  Para fazer um estudo sério, as artimanhas são tantas que só um estatístico poderia desenhar um protocolo adequado.

Comment: Na verdade isto é mais complexo do que eu pensava. Já dou pormenores.

Comment: Provavelmente o contexto em que a expressão surgiu facilitava o entendimento de cruz com martírio, e isso pode ter se perdido. Cruz, como símbolo, deve ser ambíguo há muito tempo.

Comment: @Gabriel E natural que a associação de cruz a sofrimento tenha se perdido com o tempo.  Afinal há muito tempo não ouço a notícia de que alguém foi crucificado, no sentido literal.

Comment: Me parece similar ao dito popular "se correr o bicho pega, se ficar o bicho come".

Comment: Centauros, atualizei a resposta com informação relevante que encontrei entretanto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O dicionário Houaiss, o único em que encontrei a expressão, diz que ***entre a cruz e a espada*** é o mesmo que ***entre a cruz e a água benta, entre a cruz e a caldeirinha*** ou ***entre a espada e a parede***. Nos três primeiros, o Houaiss (verbete *cruz*) simplesmente remete para *entre a espada e a parede*, e no verbete espada vem (desenvolvendo abreviações):

> **entre a espada e a parede** em situação muito difícil, a que não se tem como fugir; entre o malho e a bigorna, entre o martelo e a bigorna, entre a cruz e a água benta, entre a cruz e a caldeirinha, entre a cruz e a espada

Quando vi nesta pergunta *entre a cruz e a espada* associei logo a *entre a espada e a parede*, a única destas expressões que eu conhecia, e imaginei alguém ameaçado de um lado com uma espada, do outro com crucificação ou cruz no sentido figurado de tormento, sofrimento. *Entre a espada e a parede* é uma imagem talvez mais clara: na minha experiência, é muito usada quando uma pessoa é obrigada a fazer algo que não quer (como confessar algo), como se estivesse encurralada entre uma parede e alguém armado com espada, e não tivesse portanto como se esquivar. Provavelmente não é coincidência que os exemplos mais antigos que encontrei de *entra a cruz e a espada*, a partir de 1873, a pessoa em causa parece precisamente sentir-se coagida (grafia original; negrito meu em todas as citações):

> « Na côrte eu não tinha o direito de exigir a mais insignificante cousa para meus amigos sem o consentimento previo e demorado do conselheiro, e na provincia nenhum pedido podia ser encaminhado ao governo sem o—visto—do Sr. Dr. Freitas, de modo que, **entre a cruz e a espada**, *eu **sentia-me coacto** pela dependencia mais humilhante*. [...]
>   [*A Reforma, orgão democrático*, Rio de Janeiro, 1873](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=226440&pesq=entre%20cruz%20espada&pasta=ano%20187)
>
> [Fala o General Madeira:] — […] peço perdão de meus erros.
>   — É tarde de mais, meu « inglez republicano », meu bor… das dúzias, lê o que os pintinhos azucrinados te mandam de presente !
>   E o pobre General Madeira, **entre a cruz e a espada**, leu o seguinte:
>   [“Diario das Alagoas, 1889](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=812358&pesq=entre%20cruz%20espada&pasta=ano%20188)
>
> O velho *N’gunza*, **vendo-se entre a cruz e a espada**, homem timorato, a que o medo do *ginvunge*—feitiço—fazia estremecer de horror, declarou que nos ultimos tempos lhe haviam morrido muitos de seus filhos; que a *quimbanda* e a gente entendida da terra o accusavam de feiticeiro […]
>   [Agostinho Sesinando Marques, *Os Climas e as Producções das Terras de Malange á Lunda*, Lisboa, 1889](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gYwPAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22entre%20a%20cruz%20e%20a%20espada%22&source=gbs_book_other_versions)

As outras duas expressões — *entre a cruz e a água benta* e *entre a cruz e a caldeirinha* — vêm da mesma ideia: a [caldeirinha (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/caldeirinha) é um vaso de cobre para transportar a água benta. Encontrei esta explicação relativamente  à expressão congénere castelhana — *entre la cruz e el agua bendita* — neste [*Discursos Predicables de Diversos Tratados* de 1604](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gbX3ZCMxnvkC&pg=PA822&dq=%22la%20cruz%20y%20el%20agua%20bendita%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZuN6MtfvQAhXBWxoKHULnDtcQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22la%20cruz%20y%20el%20agua%20bendita%22&f=false) (tradução minha):

> […] todas as nações tinham um refrão ou linguagem com que dão a entender o mal ou grande tormento que tinham ou esperavam, como diz o castelhano, andais entre a cruz e a água benta, vindo a metáfora de quando o sacerdote vai dar a extrema unção, leva o menino de altar o círio e água benta, e o sacristão a cruz: e porque quem recebe a extrema unção está em grande agonia e aflição de morte, diz-se que fulano está entre a cruz e a água benta.

Conclusão: dado o que diz o Houaiss, os exemplos mais antigos, e o significado claro  das expressões congéneres (depois de sabermos da extrema unção), parece-me claro que tradicionalmente o significado de *entre a cruz e a espada* foi ’em grande perigo, sem escapatória possível’, e não ’num dilema’. Mas naturalmente, com o tempo, as pessoas são livres de reinterpretar a expressão e lhe dar novos usos.

### Origem da expressão

Com segurança, posso apenas afirmar que a expressão já estava em uso no Brasil em 1873. Quanto a como surgiu, podemos apenas especular. Respostas no  [Yahoo Answers](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080803121058AAApHjj), que o Centaurus me trouxe à atenção, sugere que *cruz* e *espada* se referem ao poder religioso e militar respetivamente. Mas a única fonte indicada (P.U.C. do Rio Grande do Sul, sem nome de autor nem título de obra) não é suficientemente precisa para ser seguida e confirmada. Nós poderíamos imaginar os judeus, que, que em Portugal por volta de 1500 tiveram de escolher entre a conversão ou a morte (ou o exílio); ou até os ameríndios que se viram de repente a braços com padres e militares da europa.

Eu inclino-me mais para outra hipótese: que a expressão tenha resultado de um cruzamento entre *cruz e água benta/caldeirinha* e *espada e parede*. Estas expressões são bem mais antigas: *entre a cruz e a água benta* existia em castelhano em 1604 e está atestada em português a partir de [1736 (Cartas do Cavaleiro de Oliveira)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=v-_3GAlzMpsC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22havia%20Cruz%20nem%20agoa%20benta%22&source=bl&ots=Hgq6Y51XSP&sig=ACfU3U16lLZ7sRJ82jziZkD5NlOl0sBiNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj3p6cvLfkAhUM7eAKHQmWAeYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22havia%20Cruz%20nem%20agoa%20benta%22&f=false); *entre a cruz e a caldeirinha* encontra-se a partir de [1823 (*Correio do Rio de Janeiro*)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=749370&pesq=entre%20cruz%20caldeirinha&pasta=ano%20182); e *entre a espada e a parede* a partir de [1836 ( *Gazeta Universal*, Pernambuco)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=813974&pesq=entre%20espada%20parede&pasta=ano%20183). *Entre a cruz e a espada* aparece mais tarde, com o mesmo significado e combinando elementos das expressões mais antigas mas que continuavam em uso. Então poderia muito bem ter resultado de um cruzamento, deliberado ou acidental, das expressões anteriores.

Comment: E eu imaginando a caldeirinha como um caldeirão de índios antropófagos hahaha!

Comment: @bfavaretto Olha, a primeira ideia que me veio à cabeça foi desse tipo, mais instrumento de tortura, tipo inquisição. Isto foi ontem; nunca tinha ouvido essa expressão.

Comment: A cruz poderia ser crucifixão (se sacrificar paro os outros viverem) e a espada poderia ser a violência (lutar matando os outros para salvar-se a si mesmo). Ou seja, um dilema moral....parece bem cristão ao meu ver.

Comment: +1 se eu pudesse.

Answer (score 3):

*Entre a cruz e a espada* significa sim que se está no meio de duas coisas ruins; ou, em outras palavras, que todas as escolhas disponíveis levam a um desfecho ruim.

A cruz, neste caso, se refere ao instrumento de tortura, não ao símbolo da fé cristã.

Vale adicionar que a expressão *estar em uma [sinuca de bico](http://www.aulete.com.br/sinuca)* (Aulete) é similar. Ela significa que a pessoa não tem mais opções (ou que não tem *boas* opções, dependendo da sua interpretação).

Comment: Sim, já usei "estar em uma sinuca de bico"  embora eu nem saiba o que é.

Comment: E a "caldeirinha", que às vezes aparece(-ia) no lugar da espada?

Comment: @bfavaretto Isso pelo menos já descobri o que é.

Comment: Sim, nessa expressão a cruz tem o significado de tortura e não o paraíso, embora possa soar o contrário.

Answer (score 2):

*Entre a cruz e a espada* significa que a pessoa está em um dilema. Dilemas sempre envolvem escolhas opostas. Não necessariamente é bom ou ruim; é oposto.

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessariamente estar entre duas coisas ruins. Acredito que seja estar em uma posição onde você tenha que tomar uma decisão entre duas coisas, sejam elas boas ou ruins.

Answer (score 1):

A expressão tem origem histórica ligada a Portugal. Vamos entender o contexto: Quando os mouros (islâmicos) começaram a atacar a Europa, eles invadiram pela Espanha e foram subindo, dominando a Península Ibérica praticamente toda. Os portugueses foram todos encurralados no extremo norte, refugiados nas montanhas das Astúrias, e os Mouros já entravam no território francês. Se eles tivessem dominado a França, hoje as Américas estariam usando burca e turbante, as mulheres ainda seriam objetos sem direitos, enfim, seríamos "diferentes"... Mas não foi assim...

Naquela época, Igreja e Estado eram uma coisa só. O que acontece é que o cristianismo dominou a Europa por mártires, não eram assassinos, quanto mais os matavam mais eles cresciam. É uma religião pautada no amor e na não-resistência, não-violência (a princípio). Os mouros já entendiam que matar em nome de Deus era algo bom, então a Europa era massacrada sem dó.

Se a civilização ocidental não fizesse nada, era seu fim... tudo que conhecemos hoje como o Estado de Direito, os valores cristãos, a filosofia/arte grega, a base da civilização atual iria por água abaixo. O mundo ocidental e o seu futuro estavam "**entre a Cruz e a Espada**". Ou eles colocavam toda a história a perder, inclusive sua própria religião, ou eles tomavam as espadas nas mãos. Entende a situação aqui? Sua religião diz para amar até seus inimigos, mas suas famílias, sua nação, são exterminadas perante eles... este é o grande dilema.

Foi quando surgiram os lendários **Cavaleiros Templários** (o símbolo perfeito para a situação), quando o cristianismo tomou as espadas enfim. A "Reconquista" do território, foi de 722 até 1492 (!), surgiram as famosas "Cruzadas" e muitas batalhas conexas.

Fica assim claro que Estado e Igreja não podem ser um só. A religião e a política devem ser integradas na sociedade, mas idealismos religiosos sem uma política protetora cria um Estado fadado a extinção perante uma ameaça cruel e exterminadora.

É uma história incrível, que tem muito a nos ensinar.

Comment: "Se eles tivessem dominado a França, hoje as Américas..."   Melhor escrever que é apenas uma conjectura.  Eu, pessoalmente acho muito pouco provável que isso acontecesse.

Comment: "Quando os mouros (islâmicos) começaram a atacar a Europa, eles invadiram pela Espanha e foram subindo..."    O Califado Almóada invadiu pela Espanha, mas a Europa também foi invadida pelos turcos otomanos a partir dos Bálcãs.

Comment: ale.nakai, bem-vinda ao PL.   Sua resposta demonstra vontade de contribuir para o crescimento do site.  No entanto, as respostas não devem expressar opiniões (a não ser quando são definidas como tal: "na minha opinião", etc) e devem conter, sempre que possível, referências para as afirmações.

Comment: Se fosse assim, porque há tão escassas referências em site:.pt??

Answer (score -1):

A cruz e a espada foram instrumentos usados  para dominar o Brasil durante sua invasão pelos portugueses.

O uso destes instrumentos, a cruz representando a fé imposta aos indígenas e a espada que os forçava a aceitar esta fé, fizeram a dominação dos povos nativos desta terra... e daí para frente só exploração.

Answer (score -1):

*Cruz* nesse caso significa ’Deus’, a ’Igreja’ ou ’o bem’. No outro polo temos a violência, o pecado ou o mal representados, em muitos casos, como manifestação do mal.

*Cruz*: igreja. Espada: pecado. Entre o bem e o mal

Comment: Isto é a tua interpretação pessoal, o significado com que a expressão é usada no teu meio, ou é o quê? Porque o Centaurus dá-nos uma interpretação diferente...

Answer (score -1):

*Entre a cruz e a espada*: boa metáfora. A interpretação do texto pode ter tido um significado a quem o criou. Mais acredito que se aplica conforme a visão de cada um. Eu estava compondo uma música falando sobre a morte de Cristo, onde os governadores não assumirão e deixaram na mão do povo ("vocês escolhem Jesus ou Barrabás") A espada arma de defesa dada a Barrabás. A cruz dada ao Cristo como emblema de vergonha e dor. Mais isso para que se cumprisse o propósito de Deus, salvar quem acredita por a humildade é corrompida.

Comment: Que história é essa da espada do Barrabás? E como é que isso se relaciona com o "entre a cruz e a espada"?

Comment: Opiniões devem ser dadas como comentário.  Assim que tiveres 10 pontos de reputação poderás dá-las.

Answer (score -1):

Entre a cruz e a espada se remete tão somente a uma época em que os homens comuns precisavam se decidir entre dois caminhos: o exercito, a guerra, ser um soldado ou o sacerdócio,se tornar padre. Não faz sentido hoje pois vivemos outros tipos de dilemas.

Comment: Luana, bem-vinda ao site. Podes fundamentar a tua resposta com algumas fontes credíveis ou alguma evidência? Uma boa resposta precisa de ser fundamentada.

Answer (score -2):

Podendo ser vista como um ditado que impõe uma condição ou situação de se fazer uma escolha, a frase *entre a cruz e a espada*, embora seja interpretativa, é uma expressão que leva o indivíduo a buscar o conhecimento humano e o entendimento racional sobre sua própria existência, simbolicamente a espada expressa justiça e cruz expressa morte.
O indivíduo após seu nascimento passa a ter seus dias contados, não sabendo qual e como será o seu fim, pois este mesmo indivíduo sabe que irá morrer, cabendo a ele carregar sua própria cruz, entre a cruz e a espada é uma jornada a ser percorrida, nesta jornada as escolhas serão feitas, o indivíduo em sua jornada irá travar muitos combates contra sua própria razão emocional e intelectual em busca de justiça para si mesmo ou outro indivíduo, a capacidade de quando e como tomar as decisões ou qual escolha fazer é facultativa ao indivíduo desde o seu nascimento e o acompanhará até a morte.
Desta forma entende-se que o indivíduo nasce para a vida e caminha para a morte, tendo ele a sua disposição optar em ter uma vida justa ou não.

Comment: Luciano, bem-vindo à comunidade. Esta tua resposta é uma interpretação muito, muito, mas mesmo muito, pessoal! Os exemplos que vi do uso da expressão não me sugerem nada dessas tuas questões profundas.